# Android app: Android Studio - formula calculator

Tags: android, sdk

I want to make a simple Android app for min.-version 2 for local use. The problem is I have never made Android apps. I've installed Android Studio and SDK Tools now, but I get errors when creating a blank app project. Actually I am a VB.NET programmer, I also know C#, PHP, but I've never done anything for smartphones before.

What I need, is a simple calculator with two text-boxes (e.g. `txt1` (a) and `txt2` (b) which are inputs as doubles), a calculate button, and a result-field (as double).. see an example-picture below.

[image]

When focusing a text-box a numeric keyboard must appear (like for a calc), with a decimal point button. And when I click on result-button then output must be calculated and printed following the formula below:

[image]

Can anybody give me a tip how to make this? Or can anybody tell where to write the code to make this app work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you need to learn how android Layout XML files work. Then add 4 items: 2 `EditText`s at the beginning, then one `Button` with the text "Calculate" and finaly one more `EditText`. Set for all of them some IDs (i.e. text1, text2, button, output).
Also don't forget to set all the items to have "match_parent" at "layout_width" and "wrap_content" at "layout_height" (for displaying as you want).

Then in your main activity class, in your on `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

```
final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
final EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
final EditText output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);
text1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
text2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
output.setEditable(false);
Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (text1.getText().isEmpty() || text2.getText().isEmpty()) return;
        double text1Value = Double.valueOf(text1.getText().toString());
        double text2Value = Double.valueOf(text2.getText().toString());
        double a, b;
        if (text1Value > text2Value) {
            a = text1Value;
            b = text2Value;
        } else {
            a = text2Value;
            b = text1Value;
        }
        double result = (a*a - b*b) / 4;
        result = Math.sqrt(result);
        output.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
});
```

Hope I helped, announce me if there are any errors!

Comment: And because a usual (and not numeric) keyboard is used, is it possible to pass through following code before assigning a and b?:
`char separator =  Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator; 

if (separator == '.') {text1.value.replace(",", "."); text2.value.replace(",", ".") } else if (separator == ',') {text1.value.replace(".", ","); text2.value.replace(".", ",");}` ... because people make serious faults when typing 4.0 and 5.0 for instance, instead of 4,0 and 5,0. I have done this for the Windows desktop version of the app.

Comment: and then at the end `result = Math.round(Math.sqrt(result), 3);` also possible?

Comment: @LowLevel No, we don't need all that separator thing, because in the code I set: `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);` which means the number is always a valid decimal number, unless it is empty (I am updating code now)

Comment: @LowLevel There is no `Math.round(result, 3)` but you can use `((double)Math.round(result * 1000)) / 1000`

Comment: I still get an error message: aidl is missing. I try to fix it first. Thanks for reply.